# Updating the Listview data from remote servers

Tags: android, android-asynctask, runnable

Hello I am trying to update my listview data on an activity from remote servers(php and mysql), I am using the Async task method to call the data from the servers, but I am calling the async task method every 2 seconds. This is how I do it

```
    /**
     * The runnable method that is called every 2 seconds.
     */
      Runnable run= new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new Comments(false).execute();
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
                }
            };
            runOnUiThread(run);



    /**
     * Async Task method for calling data from the remote servers
     */


    public class Comments extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {

        public Comments(boolean showLoading) {
            super();
            // do stuff
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... aids) {


            //This gets all the information unread from the server
            json = Function.Comments();

            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray json) {

            List<Application> apps = new ArrayList<Application>();

            if (json != null) {

                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsons = json.getJSONObject(i);

                        Application app = new Application();

                        //Values from the remote database
                        app.setMsgID(jsons.getString("msgID"));

                        apps.add(app);

                    }

                    ApplicationAdapter adapter = new ApplicationAdapter(context,apps);


                    ListView lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lists);
                    lView.setAdapter(adapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
            else {
               //stuff

            }
        }

    }
```

This logic works correctly, but I think this is not the most effiicient way to update List View on same activity, What is the most efficient to work this out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: every 2 seconds is actually a small period of time, aysncTask might take more time than that, depending on the internet speed, try increasing time a little (maybe 5-8 sec) to insure that aysnc actually finishes before starting a new aysncTask.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new adapter. Just update your current adapter with the new data. The easiest way is to clear all the data and add all the new data:

```
ListView lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lists);
ApplicationAdapter adapter = (ApplicationAdapter) lView.getAdapter();

adapter.clear();
adapter.addAll(apps);
```

And your UI will update accordingly.

Comment: this clears all the data without showing any of them